# How does 9.0 record realize value based equality for object properties (like Arrays)?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

How does 9.0 record realize value based equality for object properties (like Arrays)?

I noticed that two record objects of same type having a timestamp property which is an array of bytes are not recognized as equal, despite all bytes where the same.

Example:

```
public record C 
{
   public byte[] Timestamp {get; set;}
}
```

https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+BYAUAAQGYACBOAYwHsEViBhYgbz2NeKOOAE94BtAXWIAVAJZg4sCGAAOTAOZwYAbmJRFSgL54NQA===

will be realized as

```
public virtual bool Equals(C other)
{
    return (...) && EqualityComparer<byte[]>.Default.Equals(<Timestamp>k__BackingField, other.<Timestamp>k__BackingField);
}
```

it uses EqualityComparer which does not use SequenceEquals so the result is that two records with same content are not equal.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

var a = new byte[1] { 1 };
var b = new byte[1] { 1 };

var isEqual = EqualityComparer<byte[]>.Default.Equals(a, b);

Debug.Print(isEqual.ToString()); // false
```

I thought records would realize value based Equality for each property, but this is obviously still reference based for arrays in particular. Am I on the wrong track or is it just like that?

Comment: "I thought records would support value based Equality for each property" -- I think that's the real problem, assuming that your assumptions are specification. Especially when you seem to know very well that records use `EqualityComparer<>.Default.Equals()` to determine equality.

Comment: @StackOverthrow If you want to complain to the C# developers about not liking the way they designed a feature, SO is not the place to do it.  They're not going to see this, and the people here won't be able to do anything about it.  Feel free to provide that feedback to the devs directly if you want.

Comment: @StackOverthrow: Edgy. Lucky for you C# is just C#, so you can write your own, better code!

Comment: @sven you can take a look at Stephen Cleary's Nito Comparers library for more flexibility. The functionality that you're looking for in `record` is provided out of the box in Nito.